# How can I provide a Spring configuation bean in a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for testing?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-test

I use the following `SecurityConfiguration` class for securing endpoints in a Spring Boot application. This class depends on the `ApiConfiguration` class which provides the username and password for the in-memory authentication.

When starting a `@WebMvcTest` for a controller, then Spring also tries to initialize the security configuration but fails to load the application context.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ApiConfiguration' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

I tried adding a `MockBean` to the test class:

```java
@MockBean
private ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration;
```

This resolves the above issue, but then the username and password are null.

Is there any Spring support for providing this configuration bean for testing?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String API_USER_ROLE = "API_USER";

        private final ApiConfiguration apiConfig;

        public ApiSecurityConfiguration(ApiConfiguration apiConfig) {
            this.apiConfig = apiConfig;
        }

        @Bean
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser(apiConfig.getUsername())
                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode(apiConfig.getPassword()))
                    .roles(API_USER_ROLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .formLogin().disable()
                    .mvcMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole(API_USER_ROLE)
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use `@MockBean`, did you define mock values for `getUsername()` and `getPassword()` in your setup/before method?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Yes, I did. It seems as if the `SecurityConfiguration` class gets loaded before Mockito even kicks an. So the mock isn't actually returning any values.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a `CustomApiConfiguration` annotated with `@TestConfiguration`. This seems to do the trick. At least, Spring is able to read the properties when setting up the `SecurityConfiguration` class.

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class CustomApiConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration() {
        final ApiConfiguration config = new ApiConfiguration();
        config.setUsername("api-username");
        config.setPassword("api-password");
        return config;
    }
}
```